# pig script does not exists error , even if I can see it in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

I am trying to run the pig script using the -f usecatalog option but it is giving me issue. 
it says script does not exist, while I can see the file is present in hdfs file system.  see below.

```
[hdfs@ip-xx-xx-xx-x-xx ec2-user]$ pig -useHCatalog -f   /user/admin/pig/scripts/hcat1.pig  
    WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.  
    16/04/01 13:44:13 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : LOCAL  
    16/04/01 13:44:13 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Trying ExecType : MAPREDUCE  
    16/04/01 13:44:13 INFO pig.ExecTypeProvider: Picked MAPREDUCE as the ExecType  
    2016-04-01 13:44:13,645 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.15.0.2.3.4.0-3485 (rexported) compiled Dec 16 20                     15, 04:30:33  
    2016-04-01 13:44:13,645 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /tmp/hsperfdata_hdfs/pig_1459532653643.log  
    2016-04-01 13:44:14,184 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. File /user/admin/pig/scripts/hca                     t1.pig does not exist  
    Details at logfile: /tmp/hsperfdata_hdfs/pig_1459532653643.log  
    2016-04-01 13:44:14,203 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Pig script completed in 753 milliseconds (753 ms)

[hdfs@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ec2-user]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/admin/pig/scripts/hcat1.pig  
    a = load 'trucks' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();  
    b = filter a by truckid == 'A1';  
    store b INTO '/user/admin/pig/scritps/outputb1';
```

Comment: Why store a pig script on HDFS? The file isn't large enough to need distributed storage.

Comment: Ok.. But how would I run the job in mapreduce mode if i will keep the scripts file at ocal server

Comment: The contents of the file are streamed over stdin, to the grunt shell, probably. The same can be asked having the file on HDFS. The file has to be downloaded for the job to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the complete HDFS URI to run the scripts that are stored in HDFS.

Here is what you need:

```
$pig -useHCatalog hdfs://namenode_hostname:port/user/admin/pig/scripts/hcat1.pig
```